# Child iframe doesn't find parent

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have already seen many questions on stackoverflow about this theme, but nothing helps.

I have a simple situation:

A parent page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var global = 'I am global variable';
    </script>
    <iframe name="main" src="main.php"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

So... the child iframe page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>iframe window</title>
</head>
<body>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var local = 'i am local variable';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You see, nothing difficult.

If I find child iframe in index.php (parent) - it returns window object of child(in console), and all is great.

But if I want find the parent with any of next commands:

```
window.frames.parent

window.frames.top
```

or finding variable

```
window.frames.parent.global
```

It returns the object window of the same page, but not the parent.

It's working in WAMP and have a simple structure with index.php and main.php. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert(parent.global); // inside main.php(child) file
```

Comment: Sorry, man... But it doesn't work and that's why it's a strange problem.